# Prevent log archiving on ubuntu of tomcat logs

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu

On my linux machine I have some applications running that write logs to /var/log/tomcat7

*something* is archiving this log files, changing somelog.log to somelog.log.gz
Whenever this happens, the applications don't write any logfile anymore, only a restart of tomcat will trigger the creation of new logfiles, which is not ideal.

I've googled around, but couldn't figure out what application is archiving my logfiles, or how to disable it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps `logrotate`? Look in `/etc/logrotate.d`

Comment: Forgot to mention in my initial post that I looked there, there was a tomcat7 file, which i removed. According to some information I found, that should prevent the archiving from happening, but apparently it didn't.